# c pass a string to function then return a string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *abc = "abc";
    char *new_str;
    new_str = getStr(&abc);
    printf("%s", abc);
}

char *getStr(char *str)
{
    printf(str);
    return str;
}
```

What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: Pay attention to the compiler warnings!  And if the compiler didn't give any, either find out how to turn them on or get a better compiler.

Answer (score 6):

A bunch of small things:

1. You're passing `&abc` to `getStr()`. `&abc` is a pointer to the *variable* that is holding your string. Its type a pointer to a pointer, and that's incompatible with the `char *str` argument of getStr().
2. Your `getStr()` is defined after it is used. You either need to move its definition to before `main()` or add a prototype before `main()`.
3. The type of a string literal like `"abc"` is `const char *`. You're defining a variable of type `char *`, which is dubious (since it would allow you to modify a string literal, which is not allowed).

Answer (score 3):

here is a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getStr(char *str);

int main(void)
{
    char *abc = "abc";
    char *new_str;
    new_str = getStr(abc);
 //printf("%s", *abc); don't really need this
}

char *getStr(char *str) {
 printf("%s", str);
 return str;
}
```

Here's a list of problems with the old one:

1. No prototype for your function getStr.
2. You can't do printf(str) you need a "%s" as an additional param.
3. You need to change: new_str = getStr(&abc) to new_str = getStr(abc)

Comment: +1 for the printf() diagnosis - and I deleted my answer which just pointed that out.

Comment: `char *abc = "abc";` should really be `const char`.

Comment: You can do `printf(str);`  It is, of course a bad idea, but the compiler will let you do it.

Answer (score 2):

A C string is a pointer to a character that begins a sequence of characters that end with a null byte. The variable abc perfectly fits this definition.

Also, abc is of type pointer to character. You are passing the address of abc, ie getStr will be receiving the address of a pointer to a character--so getStr's only argument should be of type pointer to pointer to character. The types do not match up.

EDIT: Also, getStr is called before it's declared. Your compiler may allow this, but it's bad practice for many reasons. You should declare it or define it before it is used. If you are using gcc as your compiler, always use

```
gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic
```

Those three flags will conform to ANSI standards, and it would either yell at you for the above issues or not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your getStr function takes a char *, but that's not what you're passing it - you're passing the address of the pointer, instead of passing it the actual pointer.

Change:

```
new_str = getStr(&abc);
```

to:

```
new_str = getStr(abc);
```

and I think it'll work.